# How to install archlinux EFI grub with MBR (msdos) partation table?

Tags: bootloader, archlinux, uefi, grub2

As we know, EFI boot is not limited to GPT partition table, and MBR is ok.

I've a legacy disk with msdos partition table, and I'd like to reinstall it into archlinux.

In wiki:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems

it also said that GPT is not necessary.

> GPT is not strictly necessary, but it is highly recommended and is the only method currently supported in this article.

What is the way to install grub EFI boot to my hard drive with MBR partition table? Thx.

Comment: UEFI use a esp-flagged partition. Check if you have one. [Related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382372/reinstall-grub-on-a-different-drive).

Comment: Yep, one with esp and boot flag.

Comment: Then use my guide. sdb2 is supposed to be your esp partition, and sda4 your root one

Comment: But I have only one drive, with MBR partition table. I formated a useless drive to make it esp and boot (fat32, 256MB)

Comment: Yes, you have to replace those partitions to fit your drive layout. Give me your partition layout

Comment: `0-256MB fat32 boot,esp /boot; 50GB-100GB ext4 /root; 100GB-500GB ext4 /home`. I don't think it's related to the drive layout. The `# grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=archlinux` works fine with the layout, but has the warning: `GUID Partition Table Header signature is wrong`. Does this simply imply that `grub-install` supports only EFI with GPT partition table only?

Comment: Shouldn't your efi/esp partition be /boot/efi ? Give me the content of /boot. Also, I assume /root mean / ?

Comment: Arch said that `While some distributions require a /boot/efi or /boot/EFI directory, Arch does not.` in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB . I actually did both, and it worked out the same.

Comment: I bought another disk and transferred my data there, so now it is GPT partition table and works fine. (But the question is still not solved, and I'm still very interested in it)

Comment: Arch does not need /boot/efi but your bootloader doesn't want /boot... It is not the same.

Comment: I know it. You're right, but the directory will be created after `grub-install` command (by specifying `--efi-directory=/boot`). If I'd create my esp partition as `/boot/efi`, `grub-install` will not help me do so.

Comment: No directory will be created, and /boot isn't /boot/efi. Still waiting for the content of /boot, before and after mounting /dev/sda1 to it

Comment: After I did `grub-install`, if I remembered it right, there're `efi/archlinux/bootx64.efi, grub/*, initrd, vmlinuz`. The names might have some suffixes.

Comment: The grub install probably didn't detect your linux since you've mounted sda1 to /boot

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- /dev/sda1 is your efi partition
- /dev/sda2 is your root partition (containing /boot too)
- Your linux kernel file is /boot/vmlinuz-linux
- Your initrd file is /boot/initrd.img

Burn a live usb of ubuntu 16.04 with amd64 architecture, boot on it and paste these commands:

```
sudo os-prober
efibootmgr
```

Install os-prober or efibootmgr if it isn't installed yet:

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
```

Grub in efi mode is probably not installed, install it too

```
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64-signed
```

Then, install grub:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --bootloader-id=grub
```

Don't try to use grub-mkconfig, it will not work.
Instead, boot from your newly grub bootloader, you will have a grub shell, paste these commands:

```
set root=(hd0,2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda2
initrd /boot/initrd.img
boot
```

After that, you should be on linux, mount your efi partition (to /boot/efi !) if it's not already, install grub/os-prober/efibootmgr, and run these:

```
sudo os-prober
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --boot-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Reboot, and grub is back and working

Comment: Probably it is that I did not add `--boot-directory` to `grub-install`

Comment: In addition, if you hope to use `grub-mkconfig`, you can use `chroot`. (e.g. `chroot /mnt`, and then you can use `grub-mkconfig` safely)

Comment: I tried that, but if you chroot you have to bind some systems directories. Did that, wrecked everything. Also, if you use grub mkconfig in ubuntu it won't work (grub prefix)

Comment: And you mounted sda1 in /boot, should have been /boot/efi.

Comment: Oh, yep, needs binding. Wonder why ubuntu does not work. Mainly in archlinux, it would work fine.

Comment: Not sure of what I'm saying, but the problem is not with ubuntu. I saw two problems when trying to repair my grub: The real one, in the grub.cfg which is located next to the bootx64.efi. The script searched for a partition using UUID, and obviously, I was on a usb key so it was wrong. The second one is the "ubuntu" prefix, it should be "grub" or "arch_grub" for me. And the only way to fix these issues were to use grub-install in an OS you have installed, not a live USB.

Comment: if you have mounted the disk correctly, it should get the correct UUID by `lsblk`. I don't know about the `ubuntu` prefix stuffs. (In addition, the `--bootloader-id` in `grub-install` can be named anything, so `ubuntu` should be fine)